# How to install libOpenCL.so on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opencl

I downloaded intel_sdk_for_opencl_2016_ubuntu_6.0.0.1049_x64, tried to run install.sh but it says Unsupported OS, so I then read somewhere that I needed to make .deb file from one of the RPM files, I did it with 2:

opencl-1.2-devel_6.0.0.1049-2_amd64.deb
opencl-1.2-intel-devel_6.0.0.1049-2_amd64.deb

Installed them both with sudo dpkg -i, but I still don't have the libOpenCL.so that I need

Now I'm stuck... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like all I had to do is

sudo apt update

sudo apt install ocl-icd-opencl-dev

Thanks to Nick Weindberg
https://askubuntu.com/questions/796770/how-to-install-libopencl-so-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

For OpenCL on Intel GPU the simplest should be installing [the latest Linux driver](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#latest_linux_driver). Follow the generic path in the pdf guide. It contains the dev package too.

For OpenCL on CPU only install [AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) (works on both Intel and AMD CPUs).

If you need OpenCL on both Intel GPU and CPU then try installing [Intel Media Server Studio](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-media-server-studio).